# Can I use JTA over different EARs which are deployed to different servers?

Tags: java, glassfish, jta, distributed-transactions

I'm looking into JTA as I need distributed transactions (across JPA, JMS and EHCache).
I'm trying to understand whether JTA can supply an additional functionality which I'm considering.
If I have 3 different servers, each running Glassfish and each server has a different EAR (a different module of mine).
Can I have a transaction which will span across different servers and different EARs?

Thanks,
Ittai

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I have a transaction which will span across different servers and different EARs?

Yes. A global transaction can combine multiple resources from multiple EARs.

Comment: Just to verify we're talking about the same case: Server A contains EAR I, Server B contains EAR II, Server C contains EAR III. A global transaction can combine multiple resources from EAR I,II and III?

Comment: @Ittai Yes, we're talking about the same case.

Comment: Thanks, I've accepted the answer. Do you have a link to an example/tutorial of such sort? From my previous googling on JTA I was unable to find such an example (or even reference), hence my question. I'd appreciate it.